# Tkinter text widget setting tabs

Tags: python, tkinter

I have to set the tab size for my text widget to 4 characters. When I do 
`textwidget.config(tabs = ("4c","8c"))` I don't get the required results. It tabs by a lot which in now ways is 4 characters. Am I doing something wrong while setting the tabs property? Also, when I'm displaying the line and column number I do that by getting the index of the insert however here a tab character is marked as one character and not four which I would want it to be ideally. Is there a better way of getting the column number without having to deal with this problem of tabs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M-tabs) for the Tk text widget *-tabs* option mentions that a distance of 2c will be 2 centimeters. The documentation doesn't seem to say but this uses the [Tk_GetPixels](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkLib/GetPixels.htm) function to convert your option values into distances and here it states the following types:

```
<none> : The number specifies a distance in pixels.
c : The number specifies a distance in centimeters on the screen.
i : The number specifies a distance in inches on the screen.
m : The number specifies a distance in millimeters on the screen.
p : The number specifies a distance in printer's points (1/72 inch) on the screen.
```

If you want to use a distance in characters then you should use [font measure](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/font.htm#M10) using the font defined for your text widget and a suitable character like `m` or `n` given that for proportional fonts characters have different widths. An example of this is given in the Tk text widget -tabs documentation.

Comment: Yes that `Tk.GetPixels` documentation is a hard read.