# how do you adjust the tab size when using python tkinter library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to build a text editor application using the tkinter library in python. The default tab size looks to be around 15 spaces. How do I adjust this tab size to be around 4 spaces?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Text` widget's [`tabs` option](https://web.archive.org/web/20190530090959/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-tabs.html) to control where the tab stops are. The options you have for defining the width are (copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27201667/3714930))

```
<none>
  The number specifies a distance in pixels.
c
  The number specifies a distance in centimeters on the screen.
i
  The number specifies a distance in inches on the screen.
m
  The number specifies a distance in millimeters on the screen.
p
  The number specifies a distance in printer's points (1/72 inch) on the screen.
```

As you can see, none of these include a number of characters / spaces. You could just pick a number of pixels that you like, but if you want it to be as close as possible to exactly four spaces, tkinter has a way to 'measure' the width of a specific string, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32556147/3714930). Using that, you can do:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as tkfont

root = Tk()

text = Text(root)
text.pack()

font = tkfont.Font(font=text['font'])
tab = font.measure('    ')

text.config(tabs=tab)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Disappointing this answer was never upvoted. I like to use millimeters for tab stops because I use HD and 4K TV monitors which have exaggerated font sizes at times. Hopefully this unit of measure will help in the future if the Python Ubuntu stuff is ported to Google Automotive or cell phones.